# Grails Database migration problems with Spring Security password

Tags: grails, spring-security, database-migration

HI dear Grails Professionals ! I am looking for the solution for my problem.I have finished my Grails Web Application and its fully completed.I want to migrate old DATABASE to new one.There are user , user details passwords etc.The password of old users are encrypted with another algorithm.In my Grails App i use Spring Security Core Plugin.What can i do that my old user could login to new application without registration ?

Comment: What algorithm was used?

Comment: is it important which algorithm if i cannot retreive it again ?

Comment: It's not a standard algorithm? If it is a standard, you can change the plugin settings to use it (generally). Here are the docs that explain. http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#12.1%20Password%20Encryption

Comment: This is my JAva code :

Comment: md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA"); //step 2   md.update(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8")); //step 3byte raw[] = md.digest(); //step 4
    String hash = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(raw); //step 5
    return hash; //step 6

Answer (score 1):

So in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` you can specify the password encoder bean

```
beans = {
   passwordEncoder(YourClassHere)
}
```

The class must implement `PasswordEncoder`. In your class you can do whatever you did previously to encrypt the passwords.